# How to add space inbetween activity name

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity which i want to use for opening intents in my listview but using StrawberryShake doesn't look good in my list view when its used as an activity name is there a way to rename add space to an activity name in android so that in the list view it looks like

> Example A
>
> Example B
>
> Example C

rather than

> ExampleA
>
> ExampleB
>
> ExampleC

Here is my code

// example item in list
    static final String[] breakfood = {
        "Strawberry_Shake",
    };

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, breakfood));
    // Setting up the list array above

    }
// Setting the onlick listener so the array will open up activity
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openbreakclass = breakfood[position];
    try{

    // Using the class name to open up the activity  from the previous array but its 
        //displaying the dash in the list
        Class selected = Class.forName("com.example.yummini."+ openbreakclass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must be talking about the label appears on Top to the Activity you can customize it in your Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_small"
        android:label="@string/MyActivityName">
    </activity>
```

Then in strings.xml

```
   <string name="MyActivityName">My Activity Name</string>
```

even you can use some html tag with this like

```
   <string name="MyActivityName"><b><i>My Activity Name</i></b></string>
```

#### @Deprecated

OR Simply (But not recommended Hard coding String its creates issues in Globalization of app)

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_small"
    android:label="My Activity Name">
</activity>
```

**Edit :**

For your problem you can use something like this Either DisplayText & ValueText Pair or

add activityName in tags and DisplayName in Text Field

or you can have an extra TextView with `Visibility="Gone"`

Comment: But when you view it in the list view rather than it having spaces with the text it's all together as one is there any way of separating the text rather than it being MainActivity can it not be Main Activity when viewed in the list view

Comment: See updates for string.xml if you define in string.xml just edit as i did MyActivityName is just key it is not the String to display change the value to "My Activity Name" even you can use some html tag like `<i></i>`

Comment: All strings should be defined in string resources anyway.

Comment: @Daniel I have mentioned its not recommended

Comment: I have done all this and i am not seeing the label in the list only the activity name is there any good tutorials on listviews and opening activities

Comment: @JamesAdegoroye your manifest and activity code or may be layout too

Comment: Do you have an account or email i can talk to you with ?

Comment: @JamesAdegoroye Yes i do have but i think this place is much more ProgrammerFriendly

Comment: @JamesAdegoroye mailtomohitkesarwani@gmail.com

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid Check your email please

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid not received an email yet

Comment: @JamesAdegoroye I have mailed you just do as per suggestion